# Losing CRS definition saving to GeoPackage with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis-processing, ogr, pyqgis-3, geopackage, extract

I'm using PyQGIS to run the processing algorithm `"qgis:extractbyextent"`. The algorithm runs in a for loop using the current extent to perform the clip. Saving the `OUTPUT` to memory works fine and all CRS information is present:

```py
for layer in orderedLayers:
    processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:extractbyextent", {
                "INPUT": orderedLayers[layer], 
                "EXTENT": iface.mapCanvas().extent(), 
                "CLIP": 'False',
                "OUTPUT": 'memory:'})
```

If I try and save the `OUTPUT` to a GeoPackage (using the code below) the CRS information is lost for each saved layer. The context box pops up and I have to specify the CRS before the layer is saved to the gpkg. Once saved checking the layers in the gpkg no CRS information is present and adding a layer to the map from the browser panel requires the CRS to be specified again.

```py
for layer in orderedLayers:
    processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:extractbyextent", {
                "INPUT": orderedLayers[layer], 
                "EXTENT": iface.mapCanvas().extent(), 
                "CLIP": 'False',
                "OUTPUT": 'ogr:dbname=\'C:/my_filepath/my_gpkg.gpkg\' table=\"' + layer + '\" (geom)'})
```

Is there a way to specify the output CRS?

**Update**

Using just `processing.run` still lost the CRS information. One workaround is to add an extra step first setting `OUTPUT` to `'memory: '` and then using `"native:savefeatures"` to save to the gpkg.

To include the CRS in the `OUTPUT` the a_srs option can be used as shown below:

```py
for layer in reversed(orderedLayers):
processing.runAndLoadResults("qgis:extractbyextent", {
                "INPUT": orderedLayers[layer], 
                "EXTENT": iface.mapCanvas().extent(), 
                "CLIP": 'False',
                "OUTPUT": 'ogr:dbname=\'C:/my_filepath/my_gpkg.gpkg\' table=\"' + layer + '\" a_srs="EPSG:27700" (geom)'
                })
```

Comment: Looks like a bug. I suggest you to create an issue at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's derived from ogr2ogr and the 'a_srs' parameter can be applied to the output.

https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-a_srs

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce your issue with QGIS 3.16. Try using `processing.run` and add yourself the layer instead of using `processing.runAndLoadResults` like below

```
for layer in orderedLayers:
    result = processing.run("qgis:extractbyextent", {
                "INPUT": orderedLayers[layer], 
                "EXTENT": iface.mapCanvas().extent(), 
                "CLIP": 'False',
                "OUTPUT": 'ogr:dbname=\'C:/my_filepath/my_gpkg.gpkg\' table=\"' + layer + '\" (geom)'})
    l = QgsVectorLayer(result['OUTPUT'], 'demo')
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(l)
```

Your issue, that a windows appears each time to ask you to select a projection may also be related to the fact you may not have choose the transformation dialog behavior whereas your projection in destination file could be fine. So, take a look at [Deciding whether to Select Transformation in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/384591/deciding-whether-to-select-transformation-in-qgis)

Comment: I tried using `processing.run` but layers still had no CRS assigned. Another workaround I tried was setting the output to `'memory: '` and then saving the layer to the gpkg with `"native:savefeatures"`. This worked but is an extra step and I was looking for a way to set the CRS at the output stage.